# Toggle optgroup element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, toggle, optgroup

Is there any way to toggle an `<optgroup>` with jQuery or JavaScript?

I tried to change an `<optgroup>` with a normal `<option>` tag with attribute "disabled" and attach an onclick event, but it creates confusion when I click on closed select box on first time.

Comment: What do you mean "*it creates confusion...*"? How are you currently trying to toggle the `<optgroup>`, what goes wrong? When? How? In what way? What's your "*[MCVE]*" HTML and JavaScript/jQuery? CSS? Incidentally I removed the "*what do you [think] about it?*" question, since what we think is either entirely opinion-based (off-topic) or irrelevant; if it's invalid HTML or JavaScript then what we think will be answered via the code, anyway; but without seeing your code we can't offer either an opinion or an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. We just need to get all the `<option>`, append these to the `<select>` and then remove all `<optgroup`.

---

#### HTML

```
<select id="myselect">
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

#### JQUERY

```
var select = $('#myselect');
select.find('option').each(function(){
  select.append( this.outerHTML );
})

select.find('optgroup').remove();
```

---

#### JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/ehf1oh8w/